# iOS Side Menu Buttons

Tags: ios

I am trying to implement two side menus. As seen in the screenshot, I have added two buttons and also menu. However, how could I able to define which button is clicked? My code works for leftside, but not for right side.

If I know which button is clicked, then I could able to modify the rest of the detail.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    sideBarRight = [[CDSideBarController alloc] initWithImages:imageList];
    sideBarRight.delegate = self;

    sideBarLeft = [[CDSideBarController alloc] initWithImages:imageList];
    sideBarLeft.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // Right Menu Button
    [sideBarRight insertMenuButtonOnView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window atPosition:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 70, 50) atSite:@"Right"];
     // Left Menu Button
    [sideBarLeft insertMenuButtonOnView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window atPosition:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width-980, 50) atSite:@"Left"];
}

//CDSideBarController

- (CDSideBarController*)initWithImages:(NSArray*)images
{
    _menuButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
    [_menuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_menuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    _backgroundMenuView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _menuColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _buttonList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:images.count];

    return self;
}

- (void)insertMenuButtonOnView:(UIView*)view atPosition:(CGPoint)position atSite:(NSString*)direction
{
    _menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(position.x, position.y, _menuButton.frame.size.width, _menuButton.frame.size.height);
    [view addSubview:_menuButton];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissMenu)];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    for (UIButton *button in _buttonList)
    {
        [_backgroundMenuView addSubview:button];
    }

    if([direction isEqualToString:@"Right"])
    {
    _backgroundMenuView.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width, 0, 90, view.frame.size.height);
    }
    if([direction isEqualToString:@"Left"])
    {
    _backgroundMenuView.frame = CGRectMake(-90, 0, 90, view.frame.size.height);
    }
    _backgroundMenuView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.5f];
    [view addSubview:_backgroundMenuView];
}

// here is the thing needs to be fixed

- (void)performDismissAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        _menuButton.alpha = 1.0f;
        _menuButton.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0, 0);
        _backgroundMenuView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -90, 0);
    }];
}

- (void)performOpenAnimation
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            _menuButton.alpha = 0.0f;
            _menuButton.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0, 0);
            _backgroundMenuView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, +90, 0);
        }];
    });
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a way to solve the problem as follows, I added another parameter -tagID- when I initialize each button and if-else condition added afterwords

```
- (CDSideBarController*)initWithImages:(NSArray*)images atTag:(int)tagID
{
    _menuButton.tag=tagID;

}

- (void)performDismissAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        _menuButton.alpha = 1.0f;
        _menuButton.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0, 0);
        if(_menuButton.tag==2)
        {
        _backgroundMenuView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -90, 0);
        }
        if(_menuButton.tag==1)
        {
            _backgroundMenuView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0, 0);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)performOpenAnimation
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            _menuButton.alpha = 0.0f;
            if(_menuButton.tag==2)
            {
            _menuButton.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0, 0);
            _backgroundMenuView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, +90, 0);
            }
            if(_menuButton.tag==1)
            {
                _menuButton.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -90, 0);
                _backgroundMenuView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -90, 0);
            }
        }];
    });
```